# Using group by with left join and IN yields empty result

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables: `invitees` and `invitee_information`. invitees belong to `events` (third table event_id is a foreign key in `invitees` table).

I want to get the total count of invitees per event for which there is no information available yet (no record in the `invitee_information` table).

When I write the query using only one `event_id` in the where clause and anti-join pattern (IS NULL for `invitee_id` column to filter for rows having no information saved) the count is returned as expected for that given event_id:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
ON ii.invitee_id = i.id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND i.`event_id` = 18571 AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1;
```

Now in order to optimize the query to get this count data at DB level for multiple event_ids instead of getting this in a loop for each event_id, I used IN and passed multiple event_ids and used GROUP_BY `event_id`.

Expected result should be (if there is no data saved in `invitee_information` table for event_id 18569 :

```
event_id | count(i.id)
18569    |          0
```

But query result is always empty. My updated query is:

```
SELECT i.`event_id`, COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND i.`event_id` IN(18569,18571) AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your question but are you after this kind of result ?

```
| event_id | c |
|----------|---|
|    18569 | 3 |
|    18571 | 2 |
|    20000 | 0 |
```

If yes, then you need to use a `SUM(IF(ii.invitee_id IS NULL, 1,0))`

```
SELECT i.`event_id`,  SUM(IF(ii.invitee_id IS NULL, 1,0)) c
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
  ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE 

  i.`event_id` IN(18569,18571,20000) 
  AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`
```

---

Full answer :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579f5/23)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE invitees
    (`id` int, `event_id` int, `invitation_sent` int)
;

INSERT INTO invitees
    (`id`, `event_id`, `invitation_sent`)
VALUES
    (1, 18569, 1),
    (2, 18569, 1),
    (3, 18569, 1),
    (4, 18569, 1),
    (5, 18571, 1),
    (6, 18571, 1),
    (7, 10000, 0),
    (8, 10000, 0),
    (9, 20000, 1)
;


CREATE TABLE events
    (`id` int)
;

INSERT INTO events
    (`id`)
VALUES
    (18569),
    (18571),
    (10000),
    (20000)
;


CREATE TABLE invitee_information
    (`invitee_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO invitee_information
    (`invitee_id`)
VALUES
    (9),
    (4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Your one by one query
SELECT i.`event_id`, COUNT(i.id) c
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
ON ii.invitee_id = i.id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND i.`event_id` = 18571 AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579f5/23/0)**:

```
| event_id | c |
|----------|---|
|    18571 | 2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- The IN only for count at least 1
SELECT i.`event_id`,  COUNT(i.id) c
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
  ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE 
   ii.invitee_id IS NULL 
   AND 
  i.`event_id` IN(18569,18571,20000) 
  AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579f5/23/1)**:

```
| event_id | c |
|----------|---|
|    18569 | 3 |
|    18571 | 2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- The count for every event asked
SELECT i.`event_id`,  SUM(IF(ii.invitee_id IS NULL, 1,0)) c
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
  ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE 
  i.`event_id` IN(18569,18571,20000) 
  AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579f5/23/2)**:

```
| event_id | c |
|----------|---|
|    18569 | 3 |
|    18571 | 2 |
|    20000 | 0 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- If you want the count for every event whatever invitation_sent
SELECT i.`event_id`,  SUM(IF(ii.invitee_id IS NULL, 1,0)) c
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
  ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
GROUP BY i.`event_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579f5/23/3)**:

```
| event_id | c |
|----------|---|
|    10000 | 2 |
|    18569 | 3 |
|    18571 | 2 |
|    20000 | 0 |
```

Comment: @AliMalik updated, take a look at Query 4, I've removed the `IN` too feel free to add it if needed ;)